# How does IMAP/POP Server fetch emails from my SMTP server?

Tags: smtp, dovecot, mx-record, imap, pop3

I have a domain abc.com with MX record/SMTP server mx1.example.com. My IMAP/POP server (incoming server) is imap.example.com and pop3.example.com.

How does my IMAP and POP server fetch emails from mx1.example.com ? Do IMAP/POP Server use any protocols to fetch emails from mx1.example.com. How does my IMAP server knows that emails should be fetched from mx1.example.com. I am using postfix and dovecot for email service.

Please clear my these confusions.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple: Postfix just hands the mail over to Dovecot automatically as soon as it arrives instead of storing the mail itself.

Comment: Thanks for reply. :-) So, how does my SMTP Server finds that IMAP or POP server ? Where is the configuration portion ? Should we configure something like on SMTP that my imap/pop server is imap.abc.com or pop3.abc.com ? Or, are there any packages installed on IMAP server for fetching it from SMTP like fetchmail, get mail ??

Answer (score 1):

In `main.cf` you can describe how exactly `postfix` will communicate to `dovecot`. If `postfix` and `dovecot` are sharing the same host, you can setup communication using `LMTP` protocol via `unix` socket. This approach will have less overhead than `TCP` based communication.
In `main.cf` you should specify your domain and `unix` socket details

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = yourdomain.com
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

In dovecot's `10-master.conf` also provide socket details

```
service lmtp {
 unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
  group = postfix
  mode = 0600
  user = postfix
  }
}
```

Permissions on socket file

```
srw-------  1 postfix  postfix     0B Aug 17 00:35 /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp
```

I'm using `FreeBSD`, in `Linux` paths may be different.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.

I have dovecot on different server. How do I point on my SMTP server that this is my dovecot server. Like should I use, transport_maps option on main.cf ?

transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtproutes

and on smtproutes file:

abc.com.np smtp:1.1.1.1

Comment: Is mail delivering to real (system) users or to virtual users?

Comment: For virtual users.
Example my smtp server is 2.2.2.2 and my dovecot server is 1.1.1.1.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how can we establish that link between Postfix and Dovecot ?